# Erro with GDP in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I'm starting to get into GDP with Pyomo and I'm trying to solve an example from the book, but I can't, because it produces an error message.

The problem is on page 163 and called "9.4 A mixing problem with semi-continuous variables."

*The following model illustrates a simple mixing problem with three semi-continuous variables (x1, x2, x3) which represent quantities that are mixed to meet a volumetric constraint. In this simple example, the number of sources is minimized*:

```
# scont.py
from pyomo.environ import*
from pyomo.gdp import*

L = [1,2,3]
U = [2,4,6]
index = [0,1,2]

model = ConcreteModel()
model.x = Var(index, within=Reals, bounds=(0,20))

# Each disjunct is a semi-continuous variable
# x[k] == 0 or L[k] <= x[k] <= U[k]


def d_rule(block, k, i):
    m = block.model()
    if i==0:
    block.c = Constraint(expr=m.x[k] == 0)
else:
    block.c = Constraint(expr=L[k] <= m.x[k] <= U[k])
    
model.d = Disjunct(index, [0,1], rule=d_rule)

#There are three disjunctions

def D_rule(block, k):
    model = block.model()
    return[model.d[k,0], model.d[k,1]]

model.D = Disjunction(index, rule=D_rule)

# Minimize the number of x variables that are non zero 

model.o = Objective(expr=sum(model.d[k,1].indicator_var for k in index))


# Satisfy a demand that is met by these variables

model.c = Constraint(expr=sum(model.x[k]for k in index)>= 7)


xfrm = TransformationFactory('gdp.bigm')
xfrm.apply_to(model)

solver = SolverFactory('glpk')
status = solver.solve(model)
```

But when I run it I get the following error code

```
ERROR: Constructing component 'd' from data=None failed: PyomoException:
Cannot convert non-constant Pyomo expression (1  <=  x[0]) to bool. This
error is usually caused by using a Var, unit, or mutable Param in a
Boolean context such as an "if" statement, or when checking container
membership or equality. For example,
m.x = Var() >>> if m.x >= 1: ...     pass
and
m.y = Var() >>> if m.y in [m.x, m.y]: ...     pass
would both cause this exception.
```

How can I solve it?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing a problem from the 2nd edition of the Pyomo Book.  That edition is compatible with Pyomo 5.x releases.  It looks like you are using a recent Pyomo release (from the 6.x series).  Those releases correspond to examples from the 3rd edition of the book.

One of the things that changed between 5.x and 6.x was removing support for "`a <= m.x <= b`".  That syntax relied on a bit of python magic that led to users experiencing sometimes inconsistent behavior in other contexts.  Instead, you can generate a ranged inequality with `inequality(a, m.x, b)`.

Comment: Hi  @jsiirola thank you for your response. It's already solved